# Downloading NDVI in GEE App

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, download, widget

I am designing GEE App and want to download NDVI in GeoTIFF format using ee.Image.getDownloadURL for client side using following code:

```
var urlLabel = ui.Label('Download', {shown: true}); 
var btn_export = ui.Button({label:'Donwload Image (this an take a few minutes)', 
onClick: function(){ 
var downloadArgs = {
    name: 'Rice',
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    scale: 20,
    region: AOI
  };
  var url = range.getDownloadURL(downloadArgs);
  urlLabel.setUrl(url);
  urlLabel.style().set({shown: true});
},
```

but I am unable to download NDVI image.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like

> `Export.image.toDrive({image: dNBR, scale: 30, description: id, fileNamePrefix: 'dNBR',   region: area, maxPixels: 1e10});`

[UseCase UN-Spider](https://un-spider.org/advisory-support/recommended-practices/recommended-practice-burn-severity/burn-severity-earth-engine)
[Code UN-Spider](https://un-spider.org/sites/default/files/Code_GEE_burn_sev.txt)

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but I think this command doesn't work for Earth_Engine_App.